# How to query a specific tag from XML field data in sql?

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2012, shred

I have an `xml` field with the name `Payload`. It has data like this:

```
<FL>
    <Head>
      <TP>Nine11</TP>
      <RB>Test</RB>
    </Head>
<FL>
```

now I want to query the `RB` from **Head** where it's value is equal to e.g. 'Test.

I did this but beyond this I cannot figure out.

```
Select  rlogs.PayLoadfrom rlogs
```

it displays and I tried casting even.

```
Select CAST(rlogs.PayLoad as text) from RecordLogs rlogs
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal, reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following: 
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic, and your code implementation of it. 
(3) Desired output based on the sample data.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: SELECT PayLoad.value('(Head/RB)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') FROM rlogs

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15      Note that my answer ignores the <FL> -> You may need (FL/Head/RB) but add the slash to the final FL tag :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XPath to query within your XML.  If I understand your question correctly, you could (for instance) query TP or the entire XML from your RecordLogs table, and filter on the TP column like this:

```
Select rlogs.PayLoadFrom.value('(/FL/Head/TP)[1]', 'varchar(50)') TP, 
     CAST(rlogs.PayLoadFrom AS text) FL
FROM RecordLogs rlogs
WHERE rlogs.PayLoadFrom.value('(/FL/Head/RB)[1]', 'varchar(50)') = 'Test'
```

Answer (score 1):

While waiting for your reply, here is an answer based on some assumptions.

By the way, your XML is not well-formed. I had to fix it.

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, payload XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (payload)
VALUES
(N'<FL>
    <Head>
      <TP>Nine11</TP>
      <RB>Test</RB>
    </Head>
</FL>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @rb VARCHAR(20) = 'Test';

SELECT c.value('(TP/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS tp 
    , c.value('(RB/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS rb
FROM @tbl AS tbl
    CROSS APPLY tbl.payload.nodes('/FL/Head[RB=sql:variable("@rb")]') AS t(c);
```

> Output

```
+--------+------+
|   tp   |  rb  |
+--------+------+
| Nine11 | Test |
+--------+------+
```